# Regex - Match unlimited no. of words of fixed length

Tags: regex

I'm fairly new to regex. I'm looking for an expression which will return strings in which the first character is of length 1, followed by an unlimited number of words of length 3 or more.

There should be a space between each word+.

So far I have:

```
([A-Za-z]{1,1} [A-Za-z+]{3,100})
```

As it stands this only returns phrases such as:

'I will' and 'A bird'

But I would like it to return phrases like:

'I will always try' and 'A bird flew into the cage'

Any help would be appreciated. I'm using an application called 'Oracle EDQ'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply the limiting quantifier `{3,}` to the `[A-Za-z]` group and the `*` (zero or more repetitions) to the outer group matching a space + the 3+-letter words:

```
^[A-Za-z]( [A-Za-z]{3,})*$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iM1kB2/3). Note the use of anchors `^` and `$` that is very important when you need to match characters at a specific place (here, at the start and end of a word).

Regex matches:

- `^` - checks the regex engine is at the beginning of a string
- `[A-Za-z]` - Exactly 1 letter a to z and A to Z
- `( [A-Za-z]{3,})*` - zero or more sequences of...

  - - a space
  - `[A-Za-z]{3,}` - 3 or more ASCII letters
- `$` -  end of string.

Comment: Note that the `*` at the end of the pattern means *zero* or more occurrences, so it will accept `I` string, too. To only return strings with 2 or more words, use `+` quantifier instead of `*`: `^[A-Za-z]( [A-Za-z]{3,})+$`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^[A-Za-z](?: [A-Za-z]{3,})+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hA8mV2/2)

Comment: Why `[A-Za-z]{3,}` at the end? Isn't the one in Capturing group same

Comment: Seeing it again, it should have been `^[A-Za-z](?: [A-Za-z]{3,})+$`